# Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function

Tags: javascript, html

Hi everyone I'm currently a student working on a project out of my book, here is the code I am having the issue with.

```
for (var i = 0; i < numAsteroids; i++) {
    var radius = 5+(Math.random()*10);
    var x = canvasWidth+radius+Math.floor(Math.random()*canvasWidth);
    var y = Math.floor(Math.random()*canvasHeight);
    var vX = -5-(Math.random()*5);
    
    asteroids.push(new Asteroid(x, y, radius, vX));***<---line 21***
};
```

Now when I run this is keeps telling me I have an:

> Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function line 21.

But I have the code exactly how it is in my book that's what I don't understand. If anyone could help me with this problem it would be great!

Comment: Please provide more code. The error indicates that `Asteroid` is never defined, at least not in the scope of line 21. Therefore, we need to see the actual context.

Comment: Where do you define `Asteroid`?

Comment: Is your book missing a page?

Comment: Yeah, put your code online somewhere, like on JSFiddle.

Comment: You just haven't declared/included your Asteroid class..

Comment: We can only guess until you provide more code.  You currently have two answers that are pure guesses.  If you want to know for sure what is going on, you have to include all the relevant code.  Ideally, you'd even put the code in a jsFiddle so we could run it and see the actual error.  You would likely get an answer within minutes if you put the appropriate code in a jsFiddle that was runnable/debuggable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the error is coming from this line because of the `.push()` method:

```
asteroids.push(new Asteroid(x, y, radius, vX));
```

Then, the issue is that `asteroids` has not been initialized as an array so thus it doesn't have a method `.push()`.

You can initialize it like this:

```
var asteroids = [];
for (var i = 0; i < numAsteroids; i++) {
    var radius = 5+(Math.random()*10);
    var x = canvasWidth+radius+Math.floor(Math.random()*canvasWidth);
    var y = Math.floor(Math.random()*canvasHeight);
    var vX = -5-(Math.random()*5);

    asteroids.push(new Asteroid(x, y, radius, vX));
}
```

It might also be possible to get this type of error if the `Asteroid` constructor function is not defined.

Comment: Although this was also my first as well, if `asteroids` was not defined, then you'd have a `ReferenceError`, not a `TypeError`

Comment: @Adam - you could get a `TypeError` if asteroids was defined as some other type, but not an array.

Comment: Well, this can either be a `ReferenceError` (e.g. `xyz.push()`) or a `TypeError` (e.g. `var xyz; xyz.push() )`.

Answer (score 0):

Is the `Asteroid` function defined?

The following works.

```
var asteroids = [],
    numAsteroids = 10,
    canvasWidth = 10,
    canvasHeight = 10,
    radius = 10;
for (var i = 0; i < numAsteroids; i++) {
    var radius = 5+(Math.random()*10);
    var x = canvasWidth+radius+Math.floor(Math.random()*canvasWidth);
    var y = Math.floor(Math.random()*canvasHeight);
    var vX = -5-(Math.random()*5);

    asteroids.push(new Asteroid(x, y, radius, vX));
};

// Is the Asteroid function/class defined?
function Asteroid(x, y, r, vX) {

}
```